# a c iterations while skipping given values in a do while loop

Tags: c

I have a very simple problem in C. I am trying to write a simple program that outputs multiples of `10` between `10` and `100`, inclusive (ie: on the closed interval `[10,100]`) that skips `30` and `70` and outputs the values vertically.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  int i=10;
  do {
    if(i==30||i==70)
      continue; 

    printf("\n %d",i);
    i++;
  } while(i<100);

  return 0;
}
```

The program stops at `29` skips `30` and continues into a never ending loop. What is wrong?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ceyyskb.aspx

Comment: Lots of people gunning for reputation points on this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `continue`.  Instead print out the value as long as `!=` to `30` and `70`.  Also iterate by `10` instead of `1` to output multiples `10`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i = 10;

    do
    {
        if (i != 30 && i != 70)
            printf("\n %d", i);

        i += 10;

    }
    while (i <= 100); // if you want to print 100

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 10
 20
 40
 50
 60
 80
 90
100
```

Use `while (i <= 100);` if you need to also print `100`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you hit the `if` statement, you are now skipping the increment of `i`. So you never reach 100!

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  int i=10;
  do {
    if(i==30||i==70)
      continue;        //!!!! This will skip the i increment

    printf("\n %d",i);
    i++;
  } while(i<100);

  return 0;
}
```

I recommend a `for` loop:

```
main()
{
  for (i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
    if(i==30||i==70)
      continue;          // The for loop will do the i++ on the "continue"

    printf("\n %d",i);
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

mbratch correctly pointed out your problem, but you might want to consider a `for` loop for this sort of thing. It would have prevented this particular problem, since the increment is automatic.

I won't do the whole thing for you, since you're obviously trying to learn, but this ought to get you started:

```
for (i=0; i<100; i+= 1)
```

You'll have to change some of the numbers in that line, but hopefully you'll understand what they mean when you change them.

Answer (score 1):

When `i` reaches 30 the continue statements moves back to the start of the loop.

And so the loop continues endlessly as `i` is not incremented from this point.

Answer (score 1):

Your code's doing exactly what it's written to do.  The `continue` skips the increment instruction, so the value hits 30 and gets stuck there.  Move the increment to the start of the loop body, or better yet, use a `for` instead of a `while`.

Answer (score 0):

It loops forever because you `continue` but don't increment i.

```
if(i==30||i==70) {
  i++;
  continue;   
}
```

or you could use a for loop like so,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
  int i=10;

  for (; i < 100; i++)
  {
    if(i==30 || i==70) {
      continue;
    }
    printf("\n %d",i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `i` is never incremented after 30 inside the body of do..while. You'd need to increment it.

```
if (i == 30 || i == 70){
    i++;
    continue;
}
```